# Eigen packet processing for user defined types

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3

I want to use Eigen types for image processing. 
Tensor module still lacks too many features (plus it is inside unsupported), so I want to use `Eigen::Array<Eigen::Array<Type, 3, 1>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor>`.

Eigen doesn't vectorize operations with `Eigen::Array<Type, 3, 1>`. E.g. example2 in the code below results in more efficient assembly (however, conceptually it is same as example1).

I guess there are some packet_traits that allows Eigen to vectorize across different coefficients for common arithmetic types. I wonder how hard it will be for me to add packet traits for Array and how should I do it.

```
void example1(const Eigen::Array<Eigen::Array3i, 4, 1>&u,
          Eigen::Array<Eigen::Array3i, 4, 1>&v) {
    EIGEN_ASM_COMMENT("example1 start");
    v = u + Eigen::Array3i(1, 1, 1);
    EIGEN_ASM_COMMENT("example1 end");
    //  Results in a lot of movl and addl
}

void example2(const Eigen::Array<int, 12, 1>&u,
          Eigen::Array<int, 12, 1>&v) {
    EIGEN_ASM_COMMENT("example2 start");
    v = u + 1;
    EIGEN_ASM_COMMENT("example2 end");
    //  Results in:
    //  vpbroadcastd    LCPI1_0(%rip), %xmm0
    //  vpaddd  (%rdi), %xmm0, %xmm1
    //  vmovdqa %xmm1, (%rsi)
    //  vpaddd  16(%rdi), %xmm0, %xmm1
    //  vmovdqa %xmm1, 16(%rsi)
    //  vpaddd  32(%rdi), %xmm0, %xmm0
    //  vmovdqa %xmm0, 32(%rsi)
}
```

Comment: You could try to define `packet_traits` for `Eigen::Array3i` -- but (if you get this to work) this depends on the internal design of Eigen and is much more likely to break than using the unsupported Tensor module. If you don't like using the Tensor module, probably the best option is to use, e.g., `Array<int, 3, Dynamic>`, and calculate the 2nd index manually (but that really depends on what you want to do)

Comment: Yeah, I can use 2D Array, but then every time I will access coefficients or using block functions I will need to calculate indices manually (and the whole idea of using Eigen is getting clear code with optimal performance). I understand that packet_traits are internal, but first of all it looks like Eigen is willing not to change its internals to much (e.g. here https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicNewExpressionType.html they officially recommend extending internal traits), second I think I can do a pull request. Do you think it is worth contacting Eigen about this on their mailing list?

Comment: Yes, you can do a PR, but I recommend to discuss what you intend to do on Eigen's public mailing first.